# Assembly program that quits after mouse has been pressed twice

Tags: assembly, mouse, x86-16, dosbox

So right now I was only able to make it loop and wait for a click, however, once I click, the program thinks that I'm still holding the click or something, since the button status is never changed once I clicked. So the program just loops to infinity.

Here's what I have:

```
.286
TITLE ''
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK

.DATA
    clickR DB 'Right click',10,13,'$'
    ; clickI DB 'Left click',10,13,'$'

.CODE



main PROC FAR
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV AX, 0h       ; Init mouse
    INT 33h

    MOV AX, 01h      ; Show pointer
    INT 33h

mouse:
    MOV AX, 05h      ; Query Button-Pressed Counter
    MOV BX, 00h      ; Left button
    INT 33h

    CMP AX, 01h      ; Check left button status
    JNE mouse        ; Not pressed? Go back
    CMP BX, 02h      ; Check if it has been pressed twice
    JB right         ; < 2? Go to label
    JAE quit         ; >= 2? quit

    JMP mouse

right:
    MOV AH, 09h       ; Print that r-click has been pressed
    LEA DX, clickR
    INT 21h
    JMP mouse         ; Go back to mouse loop

quit:
    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AH=3 RETURN POSITION AND BUTTON STATUS](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-5959.htm) instead of `AH=5`.

When it returns `BX=1` (left button is down), repeat the query and wait for `BX=0` (button is up).

Repeat both queries once again if you need to detect double click.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!, That was a very simple thing, yet I couldn't get my head around it. Where should I post the working code? As an edit of my original question?

Comment: I don't think so. SO prefers to add a working solution as an additional answer to the OP question.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that, I will do that then.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution based on what vitsoft said**

Now, this how I fixed it (It may be not optimal, but it works):

```
.286
TITLE ''
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK

.DATA
    clickR DB 'Right click',10,13,'$'
    released DB 'Released',10,13,'$'

.CODE

rightC PROC NEAR
    MOV AH, 09h
    LEA DX, clickR
    INT 21h
    RET
rightC ENDP

releaseStr PROC NEAR
    MOV AH, 09h
    LEA DX, released
    INT 21h
    RET
releaseStr ENDP


main PROC FAR
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV AX, 0h       ; Init mouse
    INT 33h

    MOV AX, 01h      ; Show pointer
    INT 33h

    XOR CX, CX       ; Init counter
    PUSH CX          ; Save counter

mouse:
    MOV AX, 03h      ;  Query Position / Button Status
    INT 33h

    CMP BX, 01h      ; Check left button status
    JNE mouse        ; Not pressed? Go back
    CALL rightC      ; Print that r-click has been pressed

release:
    MOV AX, 03h      ; Query Position / Button Status
    INT 33h

    CMP BX, 00h      ; Check button status (None)
    JNE release      ; Still no released? Go back
    CALL releaseStr  ; Print that r-click has been released

    POP CX           ; Return counter
    INC CX           ; Counter + 1 = r-click has been pressed and released one time
    CMP CX, 02h      ; Check if this has happened twice
    JAE quit         ; Yes? quit
    PUSH CX          ; No? Save counter

    JMP mouse        ; Go back to mouse loop

quit:
    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CMP AX, 01h      ; Check left button status
> JNE mouse        ; Not pressed? Go back
> ```

If you want to wait for 2 clicks, you have to allow for releasing the button also! The above code makes that impossible because you insist on having the button being down.

Next code waits for 2 clicks of the left mouse button and the quits:

```
    MOV AX, 0000h    ; Init mouse
    INT 33h
    MOV AX, 0001h    ; Show pointer
    INT 33h
mouse:
    MOV AX, 0005h    ; Query Button-Pressed Counter
    XOR BX, BX       ; Left button
    INT 33h
    CMP BX, 2        ; Check if it has been pressed twice
    JB  mouse         ; < 2? Go to label
quit:
    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h
```